# show text from tkinter text in other text fourm

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i want to save what ever i write in `input_text` and show it in `output_text`  when i clicked `submit`

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

def getText():
    result=input_text.get("1.0","end")
    return result
    


input_text=tk.Text(root, height=10)
input_text.pack()

btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="submit", 
                    command=getText())

output_text=tk.Text(root, height=2, width=30)
output_text.pack()
output_text.insert(tk.END,getText())


btnRead.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `command=getText()` should be `command=getText` instead.  Second you should call `output_text.insert(...)` inside `getText()` function:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x350")

def getText():
    result=input_text.get("1.0","end")
    output_text.delete("1.0",tk.END) # clear output_text
    output_text.insert(tk.END,result)
    return result
    
input_text=tk.Text(root, height=10)
input_text.pack()

btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="submit", command=getText)
btnRead.pack()

output_text=tk.Text(root, height=2, width=30)
output_text.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yes thanks.one more question.when i submit, it works but how do i clean that for next try.because when i submit for second time i can see last submit to.thanks

Comment: You can use `delete()` method.  Answer updated.